# Nagios: return code of 13 is out of bounds

Tags: linux, nagios

How can I fix that return code?

[image]

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of text, but place the actual text (indented with 4 spaces so it will show up like code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution that helped me:

```
1. sudo su -
2. cd /usr/local/nagios
3. chmod -R 755 *
4. exit
5. su - nagios
```

**6. check any file**

Answer (score 3):

It is due to **permission** issue with the particular plugin. Allow nagios user to access plugin.

You can use multiple options for it as below

1. Give permission using ACL.

*setfacl -m u:nagios:rwx /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/plugin_name.pl*

2. Give permission (use only in test environment)

***chmod 777 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/plugin_name.pl***

3. Change owner of the file

***chown nagios /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/plugin_name.pl***

cross check permission using below command

***ls -l /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/plugin_name.pl***